# Why don't the if statements block bad data, but still raise errors

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The below was for a database class I took.  It is a stored procedure on SQL server.  The purpose was to prevent bad data from making it into the database.  For some reason, three of the if statements below, raised and error, but still put the data into the database.  I cannot figure out why.  This is no longer for the class, but for my own personal knowledge as the assignment was already graded.

So, why do the IsNumeric(@CC)=0 and the Len(@CC) < 12 still allow data to get into the database, even though the error is raised (I believe the @cc null check allows bad data also).  Thanks in advance.

```
USE [CIS6**]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_insertCC]    Script Date: 5/20/2014 1:14:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insertCC] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @clientID int, @CC varchar(16), @expDate varchar(10), @lastFour varchar(4)
AS

If @clientID is Null or @clientID=''
    Begin
        RAISERROR('clientId cannot be null or empty', 16, 20)
    End
Else
    If ISNUmeric(@clientID)=0
        Begin
            RAISERROR('clientID must be a number', 16, 21)
        End
    Else
            If Not Exists (Select ClientID from CreditCard Where ClientID=@clientID)
                Begin
                    RAISERROR('clientId is not in the records.', 16, 22)
                End
            Else
                If @CC is Null or @CC=''
                    Begin
                        Raiserror('Credit Card number must have a value.', 16, 30)
                    End
                Else
                    If ISNUMERIC(@CC)=0
                        Begin
                            Raiserror('Credit Card number must be a number.', 16, 31)
                        End
                    Else
                        If LEN(@CC) < 12 
                            Begin
                                RAISERROR('Credit Card Number length too short.', 16, 32)
                            End
                        Else
                            If LEN(@CC) > 19 
                                Begin
                                    RAISERROR('Credit Card Number length too long.', 16, 33)
                                End
                            Else
                                If @expDate='' or @expDate is Null
                                    Begin
                                        Raiserror('Date must have a value.', 16, 40)
                                    End
                                Else
                                    If ISDATE(@expDate)=0
                                        Begin
                                            Raiserror('Please input a correct date value.', 16, 43)
                                        end
                                    Else            
                                        Declare @checkDate date, @todaysdate date;
                                        set @todaysdate=getdate();
                                        set @checkDate= Convert(date, @expDate, 101)
                                        If @checkDate < @todaysdate
                                            Begin
                                                Raiserror('Date in the past.', 16, 41)
                                            End
                                        Else


                                            BEGIN

                                                OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey DECRYPTION BY certificate CreditCardCert;

                                                INSERT INTO CreditCard VALUES (CIS6**.dbo.HashCC(@CC),
                                                    EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('CreditCardKey'), @CC),
                                                    @CC, @lastFour, 1, @expDate, @clientID);
                                                IF @@ERROR <> 0 
                                                BEGIN
                                                    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey;
                                                    RETURN(1)
                                                 END
                                                ELSE
                                                 BEGIN
                                                    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey;
                                                    RETURN(0)
                                                 END

            END
```

Comment: I think it is because this part `Else            
                                        Declare @checkDate date, @todaysdate date;`. If you dont use begin after Else it will take one row for else

Comment: Thanks, you are right it did have something to do with declaring and setting those variables.  Once I moved them outside the IF chain, it blocked the data.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean was that you need to add `BEGIN ... END` in your code like this:

```
Else 
    BEGIN --<-- THIS ONE
        Declare @checkDate date, @todaysdate date;
        set @todaysdate=getdate();
        set @checkDate= Convert(date, @expDate, 101)
        If @checkDate < @todaysdate
            Begin
                Raiserror('Date in the past.', 16, 41)
            End
        Else
            BEGIN

                OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey DECRYPTION BY certificate CreditCardCert;

                INSERT INTO CreditCard VALUES (CIS6**.dbo.HashCC(@CC),
                    EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('CreditCardKey'), @CC),
                    @CC, @lastFour, 1, @expDate, @clientID);
                IF @@ERROR <> 0 
                BEGIN
                    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey;
                    RETURN(1)
                 END
                ELSE
                 BEGIN
                    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey;
                    RETURN(0)
                 END

            END

    END --<-- THIS ONE
```

If your IF...ELSE Block Sql Statement only have 1 Sql query, you no need to include the BEGIN...END. If your IF...ELSE Block Sql Statement have more than 1 Sql query, you need to include the BEGIN...END to let it executed all the Sql Query in your Sql Query Block.
(Took from here http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-ifelse-statement.html)